# Qt Creator cannot run gdb on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, gdb, qt-creator, ubuntu-10.04, ptrace

My setup:

- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 32-bit
- Kernel 2.6.32
- Qt Creator 2.6.2
- gcc 4.4.3
- gdb 7.1

When I debug a simple "Hello world" console application, Qt Creator complains saying

```
   Couldn't get registers: No such process
```

All solutions found on Internet rely on setting `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`, which is missing in this (pretty old) distribution.

I guess that the problem is somehow related to PTRACE settings.

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: **disable the flag *Run in terminal*** under *Projects->Run*.

Once disabled this option, the project can be succesfully debugged with the console output shown on the bottom panel of Qt Creator.